# Notepad++ and xml - replacing </ in closing element tag

Tags: notepad++, regex, find-and-replace, xml, multiple-instances

I have an XML file (1000s of records, simplified here), structure (e.g. say):

```
<LIST>
<ITEM_0>
<NAME>Item Name</NAME>
</ITEM_0>
...
<ITEM_9999>
<NAME>Item Name</NAME>
</ITEM_9999>
</LIST>
```

I need result:

```
<LIST>
<ITEM>
<ID>0</ID>
<NAME>Item Name</NAME>
</ITEM>
...
<ITEM>
<ID>9999</ID>
<NAME>Item Name</NAME>
</ITEM>
</LIST>
```

Using Regex:

```
Find: \<ITEM_(.*)(>)
Replace: ITEM>\n<ID>\1\</ID>
```

I get:

```
<LIST>
<ITEM>
<ID>0</ID>
<NAME>Item Name</NAME>
</ITEM>
<ID>0</ID> <-- This line not wanted
...
<ITEM>
<ID>9999</ID>
<NAME>Item Name</NAME>
</ITEM>
<ID>9999</ID> <-- This line not wanted
</LIST>
```

It's replacing `</ITEM>` **as well** even though (I think) I'm asking it to only replace `<ITEM>`- what am I doing wrong/how to fix? I may be missing something regarding grouping (or 'greedy'?) but not sure what and have looked all over for similar. There's a million ways to cut and dice it with something else, but it just bugs me getting so close but not there with NPP.

Help appreciated- thanks.

**Late Edit:** Even if I get the 1st replace to work right, just the `<ITEM_#>` tag, I'm still left with the `</ITEM_#>` closing tag as another search/replace operation. The problem here is the current operation replaces **both** the `<ITEM` and `</ITEM` tags...

Comment: Why not do a regular replace and replace the `</ITEM_` with something else and then run your regex replacement?

Comment: Yes, thanks, would work but take 2 replaces, whereas x2 search/replace in 1 regex solution below works OK (but with the Q there still outstanding).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, it's likely that the `.*` is too "greedy" and captures *as many characters* as it can; you need the opposite – the shortest possible match instead.

One method would be to use `[^>]*` instead – this would still match as many as possible, but only until the first `>`, so `<ITEM_([^>]*)>` would only match the opening tag and nothing more.

Depending on regex syntax, `.*?` might also work – this explicitly switches the `*` to "non-greedy".

Answer (score 0):

Thanks grawity, it helped me broaden my search to [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16104946/5477718) to cover multiple search and replace in one regex.

Trying the following works:

```
Find: </ITEM_.*(>)|<ITEM_(.*)(>)
Replace: (?1</ITEM>)(?2<ITEM>\n<ID>\2</ID>)
RegEx
```

The | separates 2 strings looked for and the ?1 and ?2 are their respective replacements.

But I have to look for the closing `</ITEM` tag first, not the `<ITEM` tag as you would logically figure. So I have a solution, but can anyone answer the question as to why the above works but the following, looking for `<ITEM` tag first, fails when we're just reversing the order in which we look?

```
Find: <ITEM_(.*)(>)|</ITEM_.*(>)
Replace: (?1<ITEM>\n<ID>\1</ID>)(?2</ITEM>
RegEx
```

Not essential, but enquiring minds might like to know. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `<ITEM_(\d+)>([\s\S]*)</ITEM_\1>`
- Replace with: `<ITEM>\n<ID>$1</ID>$2</ITEM>`
- **CHECK** *Match case*
- **CHECK** *Wrap around*
- **CHECK** *Regular expression*
- **UNCHECK** `. matches newline`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
<ITEM_          # literally
(\d+)           # group 1, 1 or more digits, you can use [^>]* if other characters than digits are allowed
>               # literally
([\s\S]*)       # group 2, 0 or more any character, including linebreaks
</ITEM_         # literally
\1              # backreference to group 1
>               # literally
```

**Replacement:**

```
<ITEM>          # literally
\n              # linefeed, use \r\n for windows EOL
<ID>$1</ID>     # ID tag, with the content of group 1
$2              # content of group 2
</ITEM>         # literally
```

**Screenshot (before):**

[image]

**Screenshot (after):**

[image]